# Error sending SubmitSM - no session with appropriate state found

Tags: sms

Does anyone knows what can generate this error in MCTEL SMSC ? I'm using custom C++ connector to send SMSes to this SMSC, but the guys from the other side (SMSC side) are telling me that nothing is wrong. This connector works with the same SMSC but with other account. I need just some more information on the back of this error to show them.

Thanks,
Ju

Answer (score 0):

In fact it was problem from the other side. Nobody is telling why.